# Written csv file with Python contains wrong format of numbers

Tags: python, csv, numpy, format, writer

This script reads a text file, takes averages of every 3 rows for each column and writes it into a csv file:

Input file:

```
2013-08-29T15:11:18.55912   0.019494552 0.110042184 0.164076427 0.587849877
2013-08-29T15:11:18.65912   0.036270974 0.097213155 0.122628797 0.556928624
2013-08-29T15:11:18.75912   0.055350041 0.104121094 0.121641949 0.593113069
2013-08-29T15:11:18.85912   0.057159263 0.107410588 0.198122695 0.591797271
2013-08-29T15:11:18.95912   0.05288292  0.102476346 0.172958062 0.591139372
2013-08-29T15:11:19.05912   0.043507861 0.104121094 0.162102731 0.598376261
2013-08-29T15:11:19.15912   0.068343545 0.102805296 0.168517245 0.587849877
2013-08-29T15:11:19.25912   0.054527668 0.105765841 0.184306818 0.587191978
2013-08-29T15:11:19.35912   0.055678991 0.107739538 0.169997517 0.539165352
```

Script:

```
data = loadtxt('infile.txt', usecols = (1,2,3,4))
with open ('out.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter = '\t')
    seg_len = 3       
    for x in range(0, len(data[:,1]), seg_len):
        sample_means = ([x/seg_len], [mean(data[x:x+seg_len,i]) for i in range(4)])
        bi = list(chain.from_iterable(sample_means))
        writer.writerow ((', '.join(map(repr, bi))))
```

Output CSVfile:

```
0    0.037038...    0.10379...  ...
1    0.051183...    0.10466...  ...
2    00059516...    0.10543...  ...
```

But when I open the csv file and sum columns it gives zero! Seems like they're not numbers. I copied directly from CSV file and it looks like this:

```
"0      "   "   0   .   0   3   7   0   3   8   5   2   2   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3       "   "   0   .   1   0   3   7   9   2   1   4   4   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   2       "
"1      "   "   0   .   0   5   1   1   8   3   3   4   7   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   9   7       "   "   0   .   1   0   4   6   6   9   3   4   2   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6       "
"2      "   "   0   .   0   5   9   5   1   6   7   3   4   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   1       "   "   0   .   1   0   5   4   3   6   8   9   1   6   6   6   6   6   6   6   6       "
```

Can someone advise how to resolve this please?

Comment: To clarify, is the section under "Output CSV" what you *expect* and the one below that what you *got*?

Comment: Output file shows exactly what I expect. but as I said they just look like numbers, but you cannot sum, average... they should be numbers so that I can perform statistical analysis. the one under is copied from csv cells and pasted here. I think this is the reason why they're not counted as numbers but don't know how to approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for this?

```
sample_means = [x/seg_len] + [mean(data[x:x+seg_len,i]) for i in range(4)]
writer.writerow(sample_means)
```

Comment: this writes both lists together in a single cell, while I want them in separate columns.

Comment: No, it really doesn't. Are you sure `'\t'` is the correct delimiter for whatever you're using to open the resulting file?

Comment: You're right, removing '\t' solved the issue. Thank you soooo much :)

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that `writerow` expects an iterable of values. You're giving it a string (the output of `', '.join`), so each letter in the string gets written to the file in a separated delimited field. If you pass `bi` directly to writerow it should at least solve that particular problem.

Comment: it does, but writes two separate lists. I added bi to remove brackets. probably was not the best way of ding it!

Comment: Using `bi` to flatten your tuple of two lists should be fine, if overcomplicated. There are simpler ways, like the construction freakish's answer uses.